# Integration of $\int_{-2}^{\infty} k^m e^{-a k^2} dk$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, exponential-function

How to solve the definite integration as showed in the title.
And $m$ is an arbitrary natural number, $a$ is a non-negative number.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Write it as $-\frac{1}{2a}\int_{-2}^{\infty}x^{k-1}\cdot(-2axe^{-ax^2})dx$ and do integration by parts. This will lead to a similar integral with smaller $k$. Eventually you get to either $\int xe^{-ax^2}$ or to $\int e^{-ax^2}$. In the first case you can integrate using the substitution $y=-ax^2$, in the second that's the end of it, the remaining integral doesn't have a better form.

Comment: After substitution $t=ak^2$, this will (in general) lead to the [incomplete gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin, try finding an arbitrary antiderivative by working out a few examples ($m=1,2,3,\dots$) using integration by parts and then prove your claim with induction.